# Can't access BIOS during boot, only removing the battery

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

Since I've assembled this PC a few months ago, I've seen this behavior. When I turn on the PC, its lights shine, the screen stays dark for around 5 seconds and then the Windows logon screen appears. No mobo logo, POST or anything, just a dark screen.

I've tried the methods below, with no luck:

- Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> and other usual BIOS keys;
- Rebooting the PC using command `shutdown /r /fw`;
- Using Control Panel, restarting the PC in troubleshoot mode then restarting again to access the BIOS.

The only thing that works is if I remove the battery, wait for about 2 minutes then reinstall it. When I do this, I can access the BIOS pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> and change the things I want. The restart happens as expected, with POST and boot logo. However, if I turn the PC off later in Windows, the next time the PC boots, the same odd stuff happens: black screen from the minute it's turned on to the end of the boot.

PC specs:

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
      Time of this report: 8/23/2021, 09:07:18
         Operating System: Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit (10.0, Build 19043) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
                 Language: Portuguese (Regional Setting: Portuguese)
              Motherboard: ASUS Prime A-520M-A
             System Model: System Product Name
                     BIOS: 2403 (type: UEFI)
                Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor (12 CPUs), ~3.7GHz
                   Memory: 16384MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 16300MB RAM
                Page File: 7298MB used, 13353MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\Windows
          DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
       System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
                 Miracast: Available, no HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
 DirectX Database Version: 1.0.8
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.19041.0928 64bit Unicode
```

Comment: Which motherboard it is and do you have anything in the manual to make the delay longer to wait for user pressing a key to enter BIOS settings?

Comment: Search for an disable Fast Boot setting in UEFI.

Comment: If you like fast boot, when you shutdown windows, hold down [SHIFT] which will take you to the recovery console and get to UEFI firmware settings from there.  You can also get to the recovery console other ways but this is the easiest.  BTW, [BIOS no longer exists](https://www.howtogeek.com/56958/htg-explains-how-uefi-will-replace-the-bios/).. like for a long time now.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I can't access the UEFI menu in any way but removing the battery. I can get into recovery console. However, when I try to boot using the recovery option, it boots directly to Windows just like an ordinary boot.

Comment: Bummer, sorry I couldn't help further.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found out what was going on. When I first installed Windows, I've turned off its fast boot options. However, probably due to an update, this feature was turned on again without me knowing it. When I disabled it, I could get inside UEFI again.

So, if this is happening to you, go to *Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Choose power button's function (or something like that) > click on the blue link to change unavailable configurations and then turn Fast Boot **OFF***. It worked to me.